# Inline onFocusChange kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, inline

I'm trying to build an inline function for `setOnFocusChangeListener`

This is what I got so far:

```
inline fun EditText.onFocusChange(crossinline hasFocus: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    setOnFocusChangeListener(View.OnFocusChangeListener { view, b -> })
}
```

And I use it like this

```
freightTimeOfDay.onFocusChange { doSomething() }
```

Unfortunately though it gives me no errors, `doSomething()` is never called.

I'm looking for two things here:

**1 -** Get a param in there so I can pass it on to doSomething().
For example

```
freightTimeOfDay.onFocusChange { doSomething(hasFocus) }
```

**2 -** Make it work :p, as right now nothing is happening.

**Update:**

Seems like kotlin already has some type of inline for this

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, b -> doSomething(b) }
```

However this isn't working for me either, `doSomething(hasFocus: Boolean)` is never called.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just to clarify, there isn't really a point in creating an inline method extension.
This was my initial objective but I later realized that using:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, b -> doSomething(b) }
```

was possible, it's inline, it's pretty and no extra work is needed

Answer (score 12):

You simply forgot to call `hasFocus`:

```
setOnFocusChangeListener(View.OnFocusChangeListener { view, b -> hasFocus(b) })
                                                                 /\/\/\/\/\
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is "b" here?

Comment: @R_G It's a boolean argument that indicates whether view gained focus (true) or lost focus (false)

Answer (score 6):

This is a sweet and readable syntax:

```kotlin
yourEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
    if (hasFocus)
        showSomething()
    else
        hideSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but someone else might find it useful.

```kotlin
"Your_edittext_id".addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        Your_Function()
    }
})
```

Just paste this snippet in your `oncreate` function.

PS: I found this solution on [this](https://www.journaldev.com/106/android-edittext-using-kotlin#edittext-textwatcher) website

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking the time to answer. However I don't think the answer you gave is related. The question has already been answered